# AWS::IAM::Policy definition with "own" resource parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions, aws-sam

I'd like to define reusable policies that, similarly to AWS Managed Policies, take their target resource as a parameter.

I aim at learning the general way to achieve it, but let's consider *StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy*, and assume I want to define its twin *StepFunctionsKillingPolicy*. I want to attach my policy to my Lambda the same way I do with the original one.

```
myLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: myLambdaCodeFolder/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      FunctionName: !Sub "${ProjectName}_DataProcessor_${StageParam}"
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref DynamoDBTable
        - StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy:
            StateMachineName: !Ref MySampleStateMachine
        - StepFunctionsKillingPolicy:
            StateMachineName: !Ref MySampleStateMachine
```

At [AWS repo on gitlab](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/samtranslator/policy_templates_data/policy_templates.json) I found how AWS IAM Managed Policies are defined and
*StateMachineName* seems to be a policy-scoped parameter (all such policies have their own parameters): How can define something similar?

Of course, I could write a (copy of a) "plain" AWS::IAM:Policy for each SFN I plan to kill via a Lambda and attach the correct policy to the correct Lambda, but it would be basically (evil) code replication, and I don't want to.

Any hints?

```
{
   "Version":"0.0.1",
   "Templates":{

      ... other policy definitions omitted ...
    
      "StepFunctionsExecutionPolicy":{
         "Description":"Gives permission to start a Step Functions state machine execution",
         "Parameters":{
            "StateMachineName":{
               "Description":"The name of the state machine to execute."
            }
         },
         "Definition":{
            "Statement":[
               {
                  "Effect":"Allow",
                  "Action":[
                     "states:StartExecution"
                  ],
                  "Resource":{
                     "Fn::Sub":[
                        "arn:${AWS::Partition}:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:${stateMachineName}",
                        {
                           "stateMachineName":{
                              "Ref":"StateMachineName"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts to using nested templates and Globals values for your Functions (grouped in each nested yaml)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do as AWS did in your link. **Develop your own parser** of such json files in python, which will take your policy and produce valid template files. You can also look at [cloudformation macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to parse your custom template format into valid templates to be deployed.

Comment: I see. I was hoping to find some "more official" way.